# Material Design "Delightful Details" Implementation

Tags: android, android-animation, material-design

Can anyone provide an example of how to implement the play-stop-pause animation from the Material Design "Delightful Details" page?

http://www.google.com/design/spec/animation/delightful-details.html

Strangely, the animation is not even used in the Google Music app...

Comment: Many things from Material design didn't get to the code - probably because material design was created by graphic designers and even android team couldn't catch up ;)

Comment: Not sure why this question is on hold... Can someone explain? I'm asking for an example implementation of a very specific task.